# The "emphasis" symbol in the editor design issue.

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above, there is a small, light grey line to the right of the "Emphasis" icon in the editor. That shouldn't be there, right?

Answer (score 4):

The fix will be in the next deployment.

Comment: It seems this bug has returned.